# Showing and hiding previous and next elements in a carousel laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, carousel

Im newbie in Laravel and Bootstrap also.

I am trying to display data from database in **carousel**.

In database I have filled few rows with text and I would like to display each **row** on each **slide**. When I click on **arrow**, one row/slide **hide** and the other row/slide will **show**.

Now, I get all slide with text under each other... I cannot find some javascript which I can do this:

```
@foreach($cards as $card)

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-toggle="collapse" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">


        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>...</h3>
                <p class="carousel_text">{{ $card->text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Can you please somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-toggle="collapse" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
       <?php $index = 0; ?>
       @foreach($cards as $card)
          <div class="carousel-item {{ $index == 0 ? "active" : "" }}">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>...</h3>
                <p class="carousel_text">{{ $card->text }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
         <?php $index++; ?>
       @endforeach
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Let me know if this works!
Thank you.

Comment: I don't have any other suggestions...  What I've sent is supposed to work